# Complex SQL Query, Count of pos/neg/zero of Ratio that's Determined by a SUM function

Tags: sql, sql-server

We're calculating the revenue difference as a percent change from Q1 - Q4 of 2012 and Q1 - Q4 of 2013. Then we need to total the positive, the total of negative, and the total of no change. All the data is in a single table. This needs to be entirely in SQL.

I've been successful at getting the 2012 results, then the 2013 results but can't seem to get them to return on the same record.

```
SELECT ID_FIELD, sum( Receipts_Total ) 
FROM QR_Dom 
WHERE quarter LIKE '%2012%' 
GROUP BY ID_FIELD;
```

and

```
SELECT ID_FIELD, sum( Receipts_Total ) 
FROM QR_Dom 
WHERE quarter LIKE '%2013%' 
GROUP BY ID_FIELD;
```

In the end I need to perform this calculation, then count the positive/negative/zero, then divide by the total counted:

```
(2013 Receipts_Total - 2012 Receipts_Total) / 2012 Receipts_Total
```

My current (hardcoded id) query is like follows:

```
SELECT ID_FIELD, (((SELECT SUM(Receipts_Total) 
                    FROM QR_Dom 
                    WHERE quarter LIKE '%2013%' 
                          AND ID_FIELD = 10001 
                    GROUP BY ID_FIELD)
                 - (SELECT SUM(Receipts_Total) 
                    FROM QR_Dom 
                    WHERE quarter LIKE '%2012%' 
                          AND ID_FIELD = 10001 
                    GROUP BY ID_FIELD))
                 / (SELECT SUM(Receipts_Total) 
                    FROM QR_Dom 
                    WHERE quarter LIKE '%2012%' 
                          AND ID_FIELD = 10001 
                    GROUP BY ID_FIELD) ) AS RATIO 
FROM QR_Dom 
WHERE ID_FIELD = 10001 
GROUP BY ID_FIELD
```

Comment: Can you define the type of `quarter`?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL SErver?  These are different databases and the question should be tagged only with the one you are actually using.

Comment: Quarter is a varchar i.e. 2012Q1, 2012Q2... etc. I am using SQLServer.

Comment: This gets me partially there but the ID field is hard-coded...

Comment: select ID_FIELD, ( ((select sum(Receipts_Total) FROM QR_Dom WHERE quarter LIKE '%2013%' AND ID_FIELD = 10001 GROUP BY ID_FIELD) - (select sum(Receipts_Total) FROM QR_Dom WHERE quarter LIKE '%2012%' AND ID_FIELD = 10001 GROUP BY ID_FIELD)) / (select sum(Receipts_Total) FROM QR_Dom WHERE quarter LIKE '%2012%' AND ID_FIELD = 10001 GROUP BY ID_FIELD) ) AS RATIO FROM QR_Dom WHERE ID_FIELD = 10001 GROUP BY ID_FIELD;

Comment: What's supposed to happen in the case where there isn't an `ID_FIELD` entry for either 2012 or 2013?  What should the percentage change be - `0`?  `null`?  `Infinity`?  Don't report the `ID_FIELD` at all?  From the sound of it your `quarter` values don't need the leading wildcards - could we get sample data/desired results to verify please?

Comment: Thank you for responding. The ID_FIELD will always be there, if it's not the the query doesn't run. There are four quarters per year: 2012Q1, 2012Q2, 2012Q3, 2012Q4; that's the reason for the wildcard. I'm looking for one query to display the result of the arithmetic equation for all ID_FIELDs, not just one. In the end I need to count the positive, negative, and 0, then display the percent +, percent -, and percent 0.

Comment: A more general way of stating my problem is: for each ID_FIELD, I'm SUMming the revenue for this year and subtracting the SUM of revenue from last year, then dividing resultant by the SUM of revenue from last year. Next, I want to count the the positives, negatives, and 0s, and divide each by a total count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement to find the exact year:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN quarter LIKE '%2012%' THEN 2012
             WHEN quarter LIKE '%2013%' then 2013
        END) as yr, ID_FIELD, sum( Receipts_Total )
FROM QR_Dom
WHERE quarter LIKE '%2012%' or quarter LIKE '%2013%'
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN quarter LIKE '%2012%' THEN 2012
               WHEN quarter LIKE '%2013%' then 2013
          END), ID_FIELD;
```

This should work in both MySQL and SQL Server.

EDIT:

If you need the difference, you can do that with conditional aggregation and arithmetic:

```
SELECT ID_FIELD,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN quarter LIKE '%2013%' THEN Receipts_Total ELSE - Receipts_TOTAL
            END) / 
        SUM(CASE WHEN quarter LIKE '%2012%' THEN Receipts_Total
            END)
       )
FROM QR_Dom
WHERE quarter LIKE '%2012%' or quarter LIKE '%2013%'
GROUP BY ID_FIELD;
```

Comment: I doubt it'd work in SQL Server, given you have a column (`ID_FIELD`) not in either the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function.

Comment: Yes, great, this returns yearly totals for each ID. Now I need to subtract the 2012 totals from the 2013 totals, divide by 2012 totals

`(2013_Total - 2012_Total) / 2012_Total * 100`
then count the ones that are positive, negative or between 1/-1